# Indesign: double entry in toc when bookbuilding

Tags: adobe-indesign

**Background:**

Our PIM software works with Indesign to generate a catalogue from all products in the PIM. Since we use paragraph styles to style certain entries in the database, we can control what has been put out, including  paragraph styles that are controlled by the Table of Contents. Our software works further with bookbuilding, meaning we split the document in several documents. Each chapter is pretty much it's own document.

**Problem:**

One of our clients has added an external document which should be placed before each chapter, contains the same style that is supported in the table of contents. This works fine when generating. However, it's displayed double, dispite its a double entry. (so we get the chapter named twice, due to the paragraph style containing the chaptername being named in both documents) Is there a way in Indesign to remove double entries? So the first one (the external document) will be the chapter, while we remove it from the original chapter and have it's sections named under it. I can do this manually off course, but I find that tedious.

**Temp solution:**

I styled the chapter paragraph for the chapter content different, resulting the chapter not named, but it's sections nicely placed under the name of the external document, thus creating the right output for the table of contents, however, i am hoping for a more adobe approached solution. So if this isn't possible to remove double name entries in the ToC, its not much of a biggy, just wondering if someone else have experience with this problem in a bookbuilding type document.

Comment: InDesign has no way of knowing that it’s a ‘duplicate’ – how could it? They’re two distinct instances of the same paragraph style on different pages. The fact that they contain the same text doesn’t make a difference; after all, what if you actually did have two different chapters with the same name? I don’t see any way of avoiding this other than manually – or by simply changing the name of the paragraph style in either your documents or the ones your client added. That way, it won’t be included in the TOC.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I figured something already like that, hence my temp solution for now, by changing style. This works perfectly well, but i Had hoped there was something like a duplicate removal, but guess i ll fly with my current solution, thanks for replying.